# How to display a sorted list of files that contains certain string in linux terminal

Tags: files, sort

Assume I have 3 folders in different directories, some of them containing some more subfolders, and in each folder/subfolder I have text files named `test1`, `test2`, `test3` etc..., which contain the string `hello` in some way. It can be just `hello`, it can be `helloJASKFNASKFN` etc.

How can I display a sorted list of those files? Say I want to sort by their names, or by the modified date. I do understand that I can use the `grep` or `find` command to search and display those files, but I'm not sure how can I display them in a sorted way.

Comment: On what operating system (Unix? Linux? macOS? something else)? Also, what shell do you use? Bash? Zsh? Something else? And how do you want to sort? Sorting by name and by modification date are two completely separate issues. And what do your file names look at? Do solutions need to be able to deal with arbitrary file names (even really weird ones with newlines)? Or can we assume simple file names with no whitespace or globbing characters? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you sort the list of files first before passing it to `grep`:

In `zsh`, you can do:

```
grep -le hello -- **/test<->(.)
```

Which looks for `hello` in the contents of files whose name is `test` followed by one or more decimal digits (`<->` being a form of the `<x-y>` pattern to match ranges of numbers), in or below the current working directory, skipping hidden directories.

Glob expansions by default are sorted by name.

To sort by modification time, use `(.om)` instead of `(.)`. or `(.oL)` by size. See `info zsh qualifiers` for the list of glob qualifiers and the list of criteria the `o` qualifier can sort by.

Replace `o` with `O` to reverse the order (`On` to sort in reverse by name).

Use `(.n)` for the sort by name to be numerical (`test10` to come after `test9`, not in between `test1` and `test2`).

If you run into a *Too many arguments* error (caused by a limitation of the `execve()` system call of most system):

```
autoload -Uz zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -- **/test<->(.) -- grep -le hello --
```

With GNU tools and any shell (except (t)csh where you'd need to put the command on one line):

To sort by name:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -name '.?*' -prune -o \
  -regex '.*/test[0-9]+' -type f -print0 |
  sort -z |
  xargs -r0 grep -le hello --
```

(add the `-V` option to `sort` for a numerical sort)

To sort by modification time:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -name '.?*' -prune -o \
  -regex '.*/test[0-9]+' -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  cut -zf2- |
  xargs -r0 grep -le hello --
```

Add / remove `-r` to `sort` to reverse the order.

Comment: I tred for example to sort with GNU tools by name, this is the input : -VirtualBox:~$ LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -name '.?*' -prune -o \
> -regex '.*/test[0-9]+' -type f -print0 |
>   sort -z |
> xargs -r0 grep -le hello --
 But I get no output. What went wrong?

Comment: Also the first command you mentioned gives the output : bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
bash: -/dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
bash: .: filename argument required
And when I try to write the lines you say to write if an arguments error comes up, the output is "autoload: command not found"

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper as the answer says: you need to use `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper, do you have a file that is named like `test<digits>` and contains `hello` in or below the current working directory?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas both in and below

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper, you can add a `echo` before `grep` to see what grep commands would be run.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think you don't need `-prune` in the last two commands. Quote from `man find`: `-prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.`

Comment: @Vilinkameni, `-name '.?*' -prune -o` is intended to skip the hidden dirs like the zsh solutions do. You can skip that part (or add the `D` glob qualifier in `zsh`) if you also want to consider files in hidden directories.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was trying to debug why the OP doesn't have output in bash. In my testing, some of the files didn't get printed with `-prune`, and without it they did, and now I see they were in "hidden" subdirectories. But that doesn't explain the apparent execution of `.` (`source`) builtin. I think the OP should use `set -x` before entering commands to print the commands before they are executed. Maybe also `unalias` on all the commands (`find`, `xargs`, etc).

Comment: @Vilinkameni, the `grep -le hello -- **/test<->(.)` zsh code, if interpreted by the bash shell would run `cmd >(.) < -` that is `cmd` with a process substitution as argument and with input redirected from the `-` file. `bash` and `zsh` are interpreter for different languages.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know that, lol. I'm using GNU/Linux since 1999. I just didn't consider the OP would try to execute the very first command from your reply in Bash, since it is clearly marked as zsh-specific.